# Save Video Library contents to XML file on remote server

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, export, xml

I have Sharepoint Foundation 2010, and one of my sites has a library which contains videos. What I want to do is have an XML file written to a directory on a remote machine, whenever the users update the list by adding or removing items. There is a desired output format that I need the XML file to match - the file is actually a playlist for a HTML5 video gallery. The XML file needs to contain the filename of the video file, and a title that the user can set in Sharepoint when they add the video to the list.

Is this possible? I have seen various web-posts saying that code can be written to achieve this, but in Sharepoint and Sharepoint Designer, I can't seem to find anywhere to add code. It's possible the administrator of the site has locked down this functionality, or maybe it's a restriction of Sharepoint Foundation which prevents me writing code functions to do this?

Edit - Further Info:

It seems that I need only write a text file to a remote directory to achieve what I need. Even so, it doesn't seem straightforward to use Sharepoint Designer 2010 to create a workflow which writes the library columns to a text file, whenever the library is added to.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use custom code to do that. You could use an event receiver to listen for item adding/updating.  Then it would generate the XML in the format you need (using .NET) using the Title and Name (filename) fields.

To write custom code, you need a development Sharepoint Server with Visual Studio. Then you would package your code and upload it to your site as a "sandbox solution."

SharePoint Designer provides a limited feature set to customise and configure your site.

Here is the MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164084.aspx) about SharePoint 2013 development.